# Perfil de facebook en un webview con sesión iniciada

Tags: android, facebook, webview

Buenas tardes, necesito ayuda con esto: trato de mostrar un perfil de facebook en un WebView, antes abría en el navegador predeterminado o en la app de facebook, finalmente ya he logrado que muestre facebook en el webview tal como lo necesito, pero ahora el problema que tengo es que a pesar que la sesión ya está iniciada en la app luego en el webview pide inicio de sesión, no sé como hacer para lograr que muestre la sesión iniciada tal como está en la app de facebook. Estoy trabajando con Android Studio usando un navigationDrawer, a continuación muestro algo de código y una imagen de la app que llevo. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.facebook,container,false);

    iWebView = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.wvfacebook);
    iWebView.loadUrl("http://www.facebook.com/uniagustiniana?ref=hl/");
    // Enable Javascript
    WebSettings webSettings = iWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    // Force links and redirects to open in the WebView instead of in a 
       browser
    iWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    return v;
}
```

[image: Muestra inicialmente esta pantalla]
[image: Luego de ingresar el security check pide inicio de sesión]

Por otro lado, si hay alguna solución para este caso, ¿podría aplicarlo para otras redes sociales?, muchas gracias.

Comment: Pudiste solucionar el error, tengo el mismo error con otra página se cierra sesión cada vez que cierro la app?

Answer (score 0):

```
Buenos dias amigo ami me funciono asi el codigo hay 
hay aspectos esteticos pero creo que esos se arreglan como tamaño de fuente     de letra y coas asi  espero y le sirva saludos

package com.example.facebbok2023;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;`introducir el código aquí`
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

import java.util.Objects;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView webView;
    private Object container;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Objects.requireNonNull(this.getSupportActionBar()).hide();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
        webView=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.facebook.com");

    }

    @Override
    public  void onBackPressed(){
        if (webView.canGoBack()){
            webView.goBack();
        }

    }

en el AndroidManifest
agrege esta linea 

 android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

Comment: Bienvenido a la comunidad, gracias por tu aporte pero OP está pidiendo que se abra facebook "con la sesión iniciada" que según veo tu código no hace, de todas formas por favor lee [cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), y también te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) así podrás ganar tu primera medalla. ;)